# Is there any option to automatically fix the data types in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring, getter-setter

```
public class BankAccount {
    private int balance;

    public void setBalance(int x) {
        balance = x;
    }

    public int getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
}
```

Here the field `balance` is defined as an integer and the methods which are involved with that field are also implemented according to that type. For some reason, if I change `private int balance` to `private double balance`, then I will have to change the return types and parameter types of the methods involved with that field. I can do this manually but for larger codes, that will become tedious. Is there any way to get Intellij to do that for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the caret on the type (in your case int) `Right Click -> Refactor -> Type Migration` and type the type you want to migrate and click refactor.

Shortcuts:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> in Windows/*nix
- <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> in macOS

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the steps to select these options:

1. Refactor
2. Type Migration

*Shortcut*: `Command + Shift + F6` on default IntelliJ settings for macOS.